# Update Data parameter of a wp_localize_script() call

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, ajax, child-theme, wp-localize-script

I'm working on a child theme, In `my-page-template.php` I have :

```
//...
$current_key= 5; //calculated result
wp_localize_script('my_js', 'ajaxload', array('post_id' => $current_key));
```

In `my_js.js` I have an AJAX call :

```
$.ajax({
   //...
   type: 'post',
   data: {
      action: 'ajax_load',
      post_id: ajaxload.post_id
   }
})
```

Now in `functions.php`, I want to edit/update `ajaxload.post_id` according to a new results. Is there a way to do that? If I try re-calling `wp_localize_script()` with the same `$name` as shown below, will this work?

```
$nex_key=8; //new result
wp_localize_script('my_js', 'ajaxload', array('post_id' => $new_key));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wp_localize_script` results in your data being printed to the page before your script tag via PHP, whether it be in `wp_head` or `wp_footer`, depending on where you've set your script to be output. Calling `wp_localize_script` from an AJAX handler won't do anything, you're returning data via JavaScript.

What you can do is put any data you want to return from your AJAX handler in a json object with [`wp_send_json`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json), including the new value you want to use in place of `ajaxload.post_id`. You'll then have access to that data in your `success` function where you can update the value of `ajaxload.post_id`.

EDIT-

In your AJAX handler:

```
$response = array(
    'post_id' => $next_key,
    'something_else' => 'some other data'
);
wp_send_json( $response );
```

In your JS:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   data: {
      action: 'ajax_load',
      post_id: ajaxload.post_id
   },
   success:function( data ) {
      var result = $.parseJSON( data );
      ajaxload.post_id = result.post_id;
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the relevant answer. I understand now that I can send back a response (the new result in my case) to the AJAX request with `wp_send_json` inside the function located in `functions.php`. Can you please give a basic example with code? And one more thing, is there other alternatives to `wp_send_json`?

Comment: I've added an example above. Is there a reason you need an alternative to `wp_send_json`? You can use PHP's `json_encode`, but `wp_send_json` is a bit more simple.